# Im setting up aws Okta and in one of the steps I see this ~/.aws/config:

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terminal, okta

What is happening here?

It looks like I have to change to a aws user? or that I have to create a hidden folder called `.aws` then add a file called `config` then below in the instructions are a bunch of variables to set.

I assume I put those variables inside that config file.

but its the `~` thats throwing me off.

what can someone translate this statement `~/.aws/config:` to a statement in english please.

Comment: `~` is shorthand in your shell for your home directory. It's the same as using `$HOME`.

Comment: im on a mac, so the home directory is where I can see my documents, downloads etc folder correct? So what this is saying is in fact create a hidden file called aws put a folder in there called config then enter the values in the document (i haven't shared with you all) in that folder is that correct?

Comment: On Mac, `~/.aws/config` equals to `/Users/your_user/.aws/config`.

Comment: and when I open my terminal I see `christopher@ens-09633 ~ % 
` which means i am already in my users file. meaning I am already within /`Users/your_user` `your_user` being `christopher` correct?

Comment: @fightTheUrgeToEatLessCake yes that's correct, just create your directory and config file and you'll be set to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can someone translate this statement ~/.aws/config: to a statement in english please.

"The Bash shell provides some variables that are prefixed with ‘~’ (named tilde) which is called Tilde Expansions.

They are synonyms for contents of other variables [within your shell."](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-tilde-expansion/#:%7E:text=The%20Bash%20shell%20provides%20some,names%20that%20they%20stand%20for)

As explained in the comments, `~` refers to the home folder of the current user.

```sh
>  ~ pwd
/Users/kevin
>  ~ echo $HOME
/Users/kevin
>  ~ echo ~
/Users/kevin
>  ~
```